# Can we automate browser settings, like disabling pop-ups whenever browser starts?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

Is it possible to disable pop-ups whenever browser started?
I don't want to use switchTo() or window()..etc to handle pop-up s

Comment: so you are getting a popup whenever your browser starts? What kind of website loads by default when your browser starts?

Comment: This is a browser specific setting, which browsers are you referring to, specifically?

Comment: I've tried in firefox and chrome as well. I need to disable pop-ups in Selenuium scripting

Answer (score 0):

What is the browser. In firefox you can do it to set the config "dom.disable_open_during_load"

[Refer [http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=19&t=16445]](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=19&t=16445%5d)